# JAVA Web project connecting to firebase (instead of JDBC)

Tags: java, firebase

I have a Java app and I want to use Firebase instead of jdbc database..
(I want it to be on internet, instead of on the local computer)
I have a connection pool singleton class and that's how I connect to the database.
Can anyone guide me how to connect to Firebase please? I really don't know how to do that. (I tried to read and learn about it but it didn't success).

```
public static ConnectionPool getInstance() throws ShiftException{
    if(connectionPool==null)
        connectionPool=new ConnectionPool();
        return connectionPool;  
}

/**
 * the actual algorithm of the connection-pool before it get's the instance (private):  
 * @throws ShiftException
 */
private ConnectionPool() throws ShiftException {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        for (int i=0;i<CONNECTIONS;i++)
            connection.add(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DBso"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new ShiftException("there is a problem with the connection to the database, Check to see if it is up and running");

    }
}
```

Comment: no its not andorid.. its Java web project :S

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup maybe this can help you

Comment: it doesn't make sense.. i was connecting to the database from the sdk.. why would i change my all thing and connect from the web?

Comment: To connect from a Java web app to the Firebase Database, you'll use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start). But note that there are also SDKs that allow your web client to directly connect to the database, such as the [Firebase JavaScript/Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

Comment: pff i really dont understand. i just want to change the connection class.. i dont want to change the whole SQL FUNCTIONS... how do i change my connection pool to firebase connection?

Comment: They says that i need to dependency in my build.gradle file. but i dont have that file

Comment: and to dependency in my pom.xml and i dont have it either

Answer (score 0):

The java support for Firebase is intended to extends its server side functionality by using Firebase's sdk. To query on Firebase realtime database or Firestore, you should write your android/ios app and/o through a web app written on javascript.

Here is a useful link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: FireBase is a database doesnt he? and my project connects to the JDBC (my current database) via the serverside... not the client side.. so it doesnt make sence

Comment: Got it. This is the Firebase's sdk for java: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: it doesnt work, already tried it! my eclipse doesnt recognize the imports of the firebase :(

Answer (score 0):

### Background Info

What I gather, from your question and other comments, is you want to use your JDBC SQL-configuration with Firebase, i.e. without changing the SQL queries, connection class, generally most of your Database layer.

This is, unfortunately, impossible.

Firebase Realtime Database or even Cloud Firestore, are NoSQL databases. They can't map directly to your SQL configuration.
You can learn more on the relationship between Firebase and SQL here: [Firebase Database for SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

---

### Recommended Solution

On that note, and for future SO users with such a problem, my recommendation is based on my experience with the same problem.
I solved this by having an EJB layer whose sole purpose is to decide what configuration to use.
For example, I want to write data on COVID-19 medical supplies to the database. What I'd do is pass the data to an EJB class in the database decision making layer.

We had different configurations based on the client's moods (I think - thanks to vague Scope of Work), at first they wanted us to use MySQL on AWS, second on-prem MySQL, then later Firebase Realtime DB.

The EJB class would then, based on a property in the `.properties` file, call another EJB class for the respective configuration; whether Firebase Realtime DB or on-prem MySQL.
So maintain your SQL implementation, then implement Firebase Realtime DB configuration separately.

All in all, you end up with lot's of classes and code, but it becomes easy to change your DB configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to connect to Firebase using JDBC like interface. Firebase is a NoSQL based database and dosen't support most of the SQL operations.

That being said. Given the popularity of firebase database, the integration of firestore with common java frameworks like hibernate for entity management is long overdue. I had recently published a jdbc driver that translates the SQL queries into operations supported by firebase.It is limited to what firebase supports and should not be used for production but It will be quite useful for small scale/hobby projects. You can check it out.

[Firestore JDBC Driver](https://github.com/shiveshnavin/firestore-jdbc-driver)

The usage is quite simple. Add dependency and a config mentioned in readme.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.shiveshnavin</groupId>
   <artifactId>firestore-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```